# Alexa Recursive Intent Delegation when using Confirmations

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I am writing an Alexa dialog with intent confirmation. When confirmation is denied I want to restart the same dialog again by delegating to this very dialog. I am proceeding like described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56821014/how-to-use-intent-chaining-with-intent-confirmation-in-alexa) stack overflow question. As described in the solution to this question I do the delegation when the `dialogState` is still `IN_PROGRESS`. In my case Alexa always responds with the not very meaningful message *There was a problem with the requested skill's response*. No error message in the application log.

My skill model and the lambda code are as follows:

```
{
  "interactionModel": {
    "languageModel": {
      "invocationName": "hello",
      "intents": [
        {
          "name": "UserIntent",
          "slots": [
            {
              "name": "UserName",
              "type": "AMAZON.FirstName",
              "samples": [
                "My name is {UserName}",
                "I am {UserName}",
                "{UserName}"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "samples": [
            "My name is {UserName}",
            "I am {UserName}"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "types": []
    },
    "dialog": {
      "delegationStrategy": "SKILL_RESPONSE",      
      "intents": [
        {
          "name": "UserIntent",
          "confirmationRequired": true,
          "prompts": {
            "confirmation": "Confirm.Intent.UserName"
          },
          "slots": [
            {
              "name": "UserName",
              "type": "AMAZON.FirstName",
              "confirmationRequired": false,
              "elicitationRequired": true,
              "prompts": {
                "elicitation": "Elicit.Slot.UserName"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "prompts": [
      {
        "id": "Elicit.Slot.UserName",
        "variations": [
          {
            "type": "PlainText",
            "value": "What is your name?"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "Confirm.Intent.UserName",
        "variations": [
          {
            "type": "PlainText",
            "value": "You are {UserName}. Is this right?"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

```js
const DeniedUserIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'IntentRequest' &&
      request.intent.name === 'UserIntent' &&
      request.dialogState === 'IN_PROGRESS' &&
      request.intent.confirmationStatus === 'DENIED';
  },

  async handle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    const currentIntent = request.intent;
    const userName = Alexa.getSlotValue(handlerInput.requestEnvelope, 'UserName');

    console.log(`DeniedUserIntentHandler: 
    request.dialogState=${request.dialogState}, request.intent.confirmationStatus=${request.intent.confirmationStatus}, userName=${userName}`);

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak('Username was not confirmed. Please try again.')
      .addDelegateDirective({
        name: 'UserIntent',
        confirmationStatus: 'NONE',
        slots: {}
      })
      .getResponse();
  }
};
```

What I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You did not specified whether you `DeniedUserIntentHandler` get triggered or not. if the error is generated inside `DeniedUserIntentHandler` then it is due to the wrong format of  `Delegate Directive`.

your return response should be like :

```
return handlerInput.responseBuilder
  .speak('Username was not confirmed. Please try again.')
  .addDelegateDirective({
                         "type": "Dialog.Delegate",
                         "updatedIntent": {
                               name:"UserIntent",
                               confirmationStatus:"NONE",
                               slots: {
                                 UserName: {
                                 name:"UserName",
                                 confirmationStatus:"NONE",
                                 source:"USER"
                                 }
                               }
                            }
                         })
                         .getResponse();
```

The reason you are deleting the intent's previous state because you want your intent action to start from beginning.

You can also use your code like this: reference https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/92334/answering-no-to-intent-confirmation.html?childToView=206243#comment-206243

```
currentIntent.confirmationStatus = "NONE";
Object.keys(currentIntent.slots).forEach(
    (slotName) => {
      var slot = intent.slots[slotName];
      delete slot.value;
      slot.confirmationStatus = "NONE";
    }
);

var delegatedirective = {"type": "Dialog.Delegate",
                         "updatedIntent": currentIntent};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing now is real one. This issue is also mentioned in amazon [forum](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/221321/intent-confirmationstatus-cannot-be-changed-with-d.html?childToView=229385#answer-229385).
However you can achieve similar behavior with slight modification. **Activate** slot value confirmation for `UserName` and **remove confirmation** for `UserIntent`.
Your interaction model would be similar like below:

```
{
"interactionModel": {
    "languageModel": {
        "invocationName": "demo app",
        "intents": [
            {
                "name": "UserIntent",
                "slots": [
                    {
                        "name": "UserName",
                        "type": "AMAZON.FirstName",
                        "samples": [
                            "My name is {UserName}",
                            "I am {UserName}",
                            "{UserName}"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "samples": [
                    "My name is {UserName}",
                    "I am {UserName}"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.NavigateHomeIntent",
                "samples": []
            }
        ],
        "types": []
    },
    "dialog": {
        "intents": [
            {
                "name": "UserIntent",
                "delegationStrategy": "SKILL_RESPONSE",
                "confirmationRequired": false,
                "prompts": {},
                "slots": [
                    {
                        "name": "UserName",
                        "type": "AMAZON.FirstName",
                        "confirmationRequired": true,
                        "elicitationRequired": true,
                        "prompts": {
                            "confirmation": "Confirm.Slot.247378890994.1277345498514",
                            "elicitation": "Elicit.Slot.UserName"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "delegationStrategy": "ALWAYS"
    },
    "prompts": [
        {
            "id": "Elicit.Slot.UserName",
            "variations": [
                {
                    "type": "PlainText",
                    "value": "What is your name?"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "Confirm.Slot.247378890994.1277345498514",
            "variations": [
                {
                    "type": "PlainText",
                    "value": "your name is {UserName} , right ?"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

you can add this single code handler:

```
const UserIntenStartedHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'IntentRequest' &&
    request.intent.name === 'UserIntent';
  },
  async handle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    const currentIntent = Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope);
    const slot = Alexa.getSlot(handlerInput.requestEnvelope, 'UserName');

    if (slot.confirmationStatus !== 'CONFIRMED') {
      return handlerInput.responseBuilder
     .addDelegateDirective(request.intent) 
     .getResponse();
    } else {
      return handlerInput.responseBuilder
     .speak('your Final name is ' + slot.value + '. cheers')
     .withShouldEndSession(true)
     .getResponse();
    }
  }  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the reply of @tahiat I was able to figure out my original problem. In the updated intent the slots object must contain the intent's slots (without a value). But his first code snippet contains an error. Ether use

```js
.addDirective({
  "type": "Dialog.Delegate", 
  "updatedIntent": { 
     name:"UserIntent", 
     ...
  }
})
```

or use

```js
.addDelegateDirective({
  name:"UserIntent", 
  ...
})
```

since `addDelegateDirective` expects an intent as a parameter.

But now I am facing another problem. I use confirmation in my dialog. When I go back to the initial state of `UserIntent` after confirmation was denied I never get prompted with the confirmation message. This is because `request.intent.confirmationStatus` keeps its value, which is `'DENIED'`, although I have reset it in `updateIntent` to `'NONE'`.

Comment: Seems to be the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895154/intent-confirmationstatus-cannot-be-changed-with-dialog-delegate-directive).